# enlarge text from pasteboard

Tags: macos, text, shortcut-menu

I have no idea how to call what I'm looking for so bear with me.

I'm looking for a simple tool or method for displaying text larger than normal. At best screen filling.

Imagine me sitting at my desk and telling another person next to me to call a number which is in one of my emails. I can either read the number or, and here it comes, mark it, hit a button and see the number enlarged all over the screen so that it can be read 2m from me.

I frequently have to share a url with someone and here this would be handy too. I can't always use the "share" button.

Is this something that already exists? Usually I have to copy and paste the snippet into an editor and resize the font to some large size but that's not very cool.

Comment: Zoom can be used. See system preferences > accessibility. Otherwise fire up text editor, make it full screen, paste the number, and hit `command` + `+` as many times you like.

Comment: It would surely be more useful to use/create a tool that passes the text to the other person's computer, so they didn't have to type it.

Comment: Please, no more comments for workarounds. I'm a ware of these. I do it. I'm looking for the real thing.